# How to reference constants Anchor generated types in TypeScript?

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

Anchor captures the constants in `target/types/<program>.ts`, such as

```
export type SimpleProgram = {
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "name": "jobs_services",
  "constants": [
    {
      "name": "USERPROFILE_TAG",
      "type": {
        "defined": "&[u8]"
      },
      "value": "b\"USERPROFILE\""
    }
  ],
```

However if I am to reference the constant with

```
const seedUserTag = program.idl.constants.find(x=>x.name=="USERPROFILE_TAG").value;
```

I get something like `b"USERPROFILE"`, how do I cast it as a bytebuffer for `anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync`?

Answer (score 1):

I realized I could have defined my Anchor constants as `&'static str`, e.g.

```
#[constant]
pub const USERPROFILE_TAG: &'static str = "USERPROFILE";
```

The instruction seeds will be `seeds = [USERPROFILE_TAG.as_bytes(), authority.key().as_ref()`

The generated `target/types` will be

```
export type JobsServices = {
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "name": "jobs_services",
  "constants": [
    {
      "name": "USERPROFILE_TAG",
      "type": {
        "defined": "&'staticstr"
      },
      "value": "\"USERPROFILE\""
    },
```

Finally, I need to parse the double quotes in my Typescript

```
const seedUserTag = JSON.parse(program.idl.constants.find(x=>x.name=="USERPROFILE_TAG").value);
```

Though I am not sure if there is any better way to parse the double quoted string instead of having to `JSON.parse`?